# Entity framework : tracking entities by context

Tags: frameworks, entity, dbcontext

I was reading Microsoft document about Entity framework and Attach method which I copy the line I need help to understand below:

"If you have an entity that you know already exists in the database but which is not currently being tracked by the context,...."
and now I have  some questions : in what situation and entity might not be tracked by a context? Actually, what does it mean when we say "track" ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in what situation and entity might not be tracked by a context?

When you put AsNoTracking() in the LINQ, it will not be tracked. AsNoTracking() is one of the methods we use to improve query performance. If you use AsNoTracking(), you will get significant performance. **Sometimes you may want to get entities back from a query but not have those entities be tracked by the context. This may result in better performance when querying for large numbers of entities in read-only scenarios.** Please see Microsoft official doc (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556203)

> Actually, what does it mean when we say "track" ?

Entity framework check if you make any change to data and save it. Entity framework will have a tracking mechanism handles that for you. This is a Microsoft article to talk about when to use track and when to not trak. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Comment: Thank you very much